# Call function with parameters via databinding

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

OK Im at a crossroads with something.  Take a gander at the code below.  I have a data repeater, and throughout the repeater I want to call GetNavUrl, supplying it with a parameter found in my data I am binding with.

```
NavigateUrl='<%# GetNavUrl(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ProductCode") %>'
```

So, for example, I want navigateURL to equal the result of GetNavUrl(123), Any ideas?  thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do databinding of child objects in your UI? Honestly, in situations like these, I find it much better to avoid doing such binding in the UI (mostly for separation of concerns), and instead do that in the code behind.

```
myRepeater.ItemCreated += new ItemsCreatedEventHandler(whatever);
```

Then, in your item created event handler, find your control and assign that data programmatically:

```
MyBindedObject dataItem = e.Item.DataItem as MyBindedObject;
HyperLink myLink = e.Item.FindControl("myControl") as HyperLink;

if(myLink != null)
   myLink.NavigateUrl = GetNavUrl(dataItem);
```

Comment: Thanks Tejs, if I have to I can def do so.. was just hoping to provide some quick databinding to an already existing page